# Загрузка изображений в медиабиблиотеку Wordpress при создании поста

Tags: wordpress, upload, media-library

По умолчанию в медиабиблиотеку Wordpress изображения при создании поста автоматически загружаются в папки /wp-content/uploads/year/month/. Последние три папки Wordpress, как известно, генерит автоматически.
Как можно углубить структуру и дополнительно генерить папки /day/post_ID/, и чтобы уже в папку post_ID автоматически загружались изображения.
Перерыл, вроде, все.

Answer (score 0):

Ларчик открывался просто.
Плагин Custom Upload Dir